# procedure to insert data from 2 tables datewise into temp table

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables

Table `t_prj` has columns:

```
PID     Date    Particular
```

The second table `t_Adv` has columns

```
PID     Date    Particular
```

I want to merge and insert data from both tables into temp table date wise

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what do you expect from us now?

Comment: What are the rules regarding matching column values but differing row values?

Answer (score 0):

To create a temporary table and transfer the data from one table to it (assumptions made as to data types:

```
create table #temp (PID int, Date date, Particular nvarchar(50))

insert into #temp
    (PID, Date, Particular)
select PID, Date, Particular from t_prj

 -- don't forget to drop the temporary table at the end
drop table #temp
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,  that i know but i want to merger data from 2 tables t_prj and t_adv Date wise and insert into temp table

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of @ChrisBD answer,

```
create table #temp (PID int, Date date, Particular nvarchar(50))

insert into #temp (PID, Date, Particular)
select PID, Date, Particular from t_prj


insert into #temp (PID, Date, Particular)
select PID, Date, Particular from t_Adv

SELECT  *
FROM    #temp
ORDER   BY date

 -- don't forget to drop the temporary table at the end
drop table #temp
```